# Why is my date comparison not working in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, date

I have pretty extensively researched this issue, and I've found some useful information, but I haven't been able to solve my problem. All I'm trying to do is parse a date and compare it to another date. Seems simple, right? Here is what I've tried:

```
    function getCurrentDate() { //this function simply returns today's date
                var today = new Date();
                var dd = today.getDate();
                var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; 
                var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

                if (dd < 10) {
                    dd = '0' + dd
                }

                if (mm < 10) {
                    mm = '0' + mm
                }
                today = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
                return today; 
}

$("#TxtDate").blur(function () {
            var projectDueDate = Date.parse($("#lblDueDate").val()); //parses the project due date label to create a date variable
            var itemDueDate = new Date($("#TxtDate").val()); //parses the value the user entered into the due date box to create a date variable
            var actualProjectDueDate = new Date(projectDueDate);

            if (Date.parse(document.getElementById('TxtDate').value) > getCurrentDate()) {
                alert("The date you entered precedes today's date. Please enter a valid date.");
                $("#TxtDate").val() = "";
            }
        });
```

The `if` statement isn't working in the `TxtDate` `blur` function. It is not showing the alert window, even though I am entering a date that precedes today's date. As you can see, I've tried some different things. Any suggestions?

Comment: When dealing with dates everything *seems* simple. Its not. use a library - http://momentjs.com

Comment: You're comparing a date to a string...

Comment: BTW, bith answers are correct, but for that matter why go from `Date` to `string` and back to `Date` - you already know how to get today's date as a date object (you did it in `getCurrentDate`)

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the helpful pointers. I knew it had to be something I was simply missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function `getCurrentDate` is returning a `string` not a `date object` and you are comparing it with `date object`. So you need to parse the return value of `getCurrentDate`.

```
if (Date.parse(document.getElementById('TxtDate').value) > Date.parse( getCurrentDate())) {
  alert("The date you entered precedes today's date. Please enter a valid date.");
  $("#TxtLeaveFrom").val() = "";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. You're right; however it appears that an additional problem has occurred. `Date.parse(document.getElementById('TxtDate').value` is returning an unintelligible value : `1465876800000`. Do you know how to get around this?

Comment: yes `Date.parse` returns something like this

Answer (score 0):

`Date.parse()` returns a date object while `getCurrentDate()` returns a string. Add the `Date.parse()` there too:

```
if (Date.parse(document.getElementById('TxtDate').value) > Date.parse(getCurrentDate()))
```